# String resource ID error when setting text in edit text

Tags: android, android-resources, settext

I have the following code.

```
if (j == 0) { // Age units.
    if (button.equals(findViewById(R.id.years)))
        q19Text.setText(yearsDiff);

    if (button.equals(findViewById(R.id.months)))
        q19Text.setText(monthsDiff);

    if (button.equals(findViewById(R.id.weeks)))
        q19Text.setText(daysDiff);

    if (button.equals(findViewById(R.id.days)))
        q19Text.setText(weeksDiff);
}
```

Button is a radio button. Any one that I click gives me this error

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x2344
```

But, as you can see, I'm not trying to access the strings resource file. I'm trying to set the text of an already instantiated edit text.

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the `setText(int id)` method. Cast your integer to String and you should be fine. You can also add `.setText("" + weeksDiff)` to you code and it will treat it as string

Comment: Right idea here, however, String.valueOf(weeksDiff) is a bit cleaner than the concat on an empty string.

Comment: You can also use this .setText( String.format( "%s", weeksDiff ) )